# How to tokenize a list of words using nltk?

Tags: python, list, nltk, tokenize, cpu-word

I have a text dataset. Those dataset consist of many lines that each lines are consist of two sentences split by tab, like this :

```
this is string 1, first sentence.    this is string 2, first sentence.
this is string 1, second sentence.    this is string 2, second sentence.
```

and then I have split the datatext by this code :

```
#file readdata.py
from globalvariable import *
import os


class readdata:
    def dataAyat(self):
        global kalimatayat
        fo = open(os.path.join('E:\dataset','dataset.txt'),"r")
        line = []
        for line in fo.readlines():
            datatxt = line.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
            newdatatxt = [x.split('\t') for x in datatxt]
            kalimatayat.append(newdatatxt)
            print newdatatxt

readdata().dataAyat()
```

it works and the output is :

```
[['this is string 1, first sentence.'],['this is string 2, first sentence.']]
[['this is string 1, second sentence.'],['this is string 2, second sentence.']]
```

---

what I want to do is tokenize those list using nltk word tokenize, and the output I expect is like this :

```
[['this' , 'is' , 'string' , '1' , ',' , 'first' , 'sentence' , '.'],['this' , 'is' , 'string' , '2' , ',' , 'first' , 'sentence' , '.']]
[['this' , 'is' , 'string' , '1' , ',' , 'second' , 'sentence' , '.'],['this' , 'is' , 'string' , '2' , ',' , 'second' , 'sentence' , '.']]
```

anybody knows how to tokenize to be like the output above?
I want to code a tokenize function in "tokenizer.py" and call it all in "mainfile.py"

Comment: Yes, but it is a string. I want to tokenize a list of sentences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tokenize the list of sentences, iterate over it and store the results in a list:

```
data = [[['this is string 1, first sentence.'],['this is string 2, first sentence.']],
[['this is string 1, second sentence.'],['this is string 2, second sentence.']]]
results = []
for sentence in data:
    sentence_results = []
    for s in sentence:
        sentence_results.append(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence))
    results.append(sentence_results)
```

results will be something like

```
[[['this' , 'is' , 'string' , '1' , ',' , 'first' , 'sentence' , '.'],  
  ['this' , 'is' , 'string' , '2' , ',' , 'first' , 'sentence' , '.']], 
[['this' , 'is' , 'string' , '1' , ',' , 'second' , 'sentence' , '.'],
  ['this' , 'is' , 'string' , '2' , ',' , 'second' , 'sentence' , '.']]]
```

Comment: pardon me, sir. I want to ask again. if readdata and tokenizer apart in two py files (readdata.py and tokenizer.py) and I want to join them in main file (mainfile.py), how to code a tokenizer.py and mainfile.py to tokenize like the results above?

Comment: Uhm I'm not sure I understand your question. Firstly, you need to get the text as something that can be handled. In your `readData` function you seem to store it in a global `kalimatayat` list (which should _definitely_ be replaced by a class member). That variable is basically what I called `data` in the example I gave in my answer.

Comment: hmmm so "data" is a "kalimatayat". ok sir, I'll try. After all, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I have edited the question, sir. you may check it again.